# Enable the Java SecurityManager with AllPermission

Tags: java, java-security, securitymanager

I'm trying to get myself familiar with the `SecurityManager` but even this simple scenario fails. When I run the following from inside my IDE or from command line I get the following [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7699/abgjt/index.html);

```
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.home" "read")
```

I thought I allowed everything with this code:

> ```
> Policy.setPolicy(new Policy() {
>
>     @Override
>     public PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource codesource) {
>         Permissions perm = new Permissions();
>         perm.add(new AllPermission());
>         return perm;
>     }
> });
> System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
> ```

Has this something to-do with the derived policy from the JVM? How can I cleanly `setPolicy()`?

The same misunderstanding seems to happen for the following code:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
final Permissions allPermission = new Permissions();
allPermission.add(new AllPermission());
AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
    return null;
}, new AccessControlContext(new ProtectionDomain[]{new ProtectionDomain(null, allPermission)}));
```

**Update**: the second case is understandable as the provided permission is only a further restriction: (javadoc) *The action is performed with the intersection of the permissions possessed by the caller's protection domain, and those possessed by the domains represented by the specified `AccessControlContext`*

Comment: I'm trying to increase security of my java application and for that I need to understand the mechanisms. Just enabling the SecurityManager is not possible as I need a few exceptions. I have to understand a bit more how this all works together as it is not a standard use case.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this (tried on JDK 8 and 11). I doubt the default policy implementation to be the cause. Something non-standard interposes between the security manager and your custom policy, effectively preventing or overriding queries to the latter; e.g. a custom class loader having assigned a [static](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.security.CodeSource,java.security.PermissionCollection)), unprivileged protection domain to your classes.

Comment: @Uux Thanks a lot for taking the time. So in your case you can access the java.home property? If yes, can you gist your policy file?

Comment: @Karussell Yes, your snippet runs just fine (within a plain old `main` method, launched via plain old `java -cp <classpath> <main-class>`). I didn't modify my .policy file, because it ultimately doesn't matter -- once `Policy.setPolicy` has returned, it is *your* policy implementation that gets consulted, not the previous, default, file-backed one. You might want to try running with `-Djava.security.debug="access,failure"` and attach its output to your question.

Comment: I now better understand what I was trying to achieve: I want a programmatic way to set the policy where I see that if I set no permision then the System.getProperty call fails and if I grant PropertyPermission or AllPermission then the call goes through. And indeed the 2nd part works now (no idea why) but the 1st part goes through without any permission. And when I do Policy.getPolicy exactly the opposite happens (both parts fail,)

Comment: Related but not quite duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458821/policy-setpolicy-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to recreate your case with an extra [`Policy.getPolicy()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/security/Policy.java#l149) before the `Policy.setPolicy()` call, the reason why it affects the behaviour is that with the get policy call, you trigger a default policy creation, and permissions from `java.policy` are set, but without a `setSecurityManager()` they are not activated, that is the reason when you do a custom `AllPermission` policy set, you still get a `"java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.home" "read"` issue, for many of such default policies are not overridden with the set policy. Very confusing structure indeed.

```
Policy.getPolicy();
Policy.setPolicy(policyWithAllPermission);
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
// results in 'access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.home" "read")'
```

But if you use the following custom policy;

```
Policy allPermissionPolicy = new Policy() {

    @Override
    public boolean implies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

It overrides all permission definitions, and lets all actions through, a possible fix for this confusion.

Comment: Turns out you were intuitively on the right track from the very beginning (extra credit for having caught the OP's reference of calling `getPolicy` in addition to, and prior to, `setPolicy`, in the comments)! As for the *"why, exactly"* part of the story, see source of `java.security.Policy#initPolicy`.

Answer (score 1):

In which context are you running your code above ?

from command line with a simple JVM or inside a webapp running on top of some JavaEE container? On which OS? with which JVM (Oracle, OpenJDK, IBM J9...) and which version?

If you're running from command line, have a look at the [`java.policy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) file located in your JVM installation path. Its content may narrow your grants and thus prevent you from accessing this particular system variable ?

Comment: Have updated my question. So the policy file overwrites Policy.setPolicy? If this is really the case the javadocs for this method are more than misleading IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, if you need SecurityManager that will allow everything, just use this:

```java
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm, Object context) {
    }
});
```